# How to vertically and horizontally center a custom horizontal scroll menu

Tags: html, css

Hello I am new to `HTML` and `CSS`, my goal is to create my home page for my own website/portfolio, however I am having a lot of trouble. I have created a horizontal scroll menu with custom text, however I want the scrollable menu to be vertically aligned in the middle of my home page. What am I doing wrong or how do I add this feature.

[image: This is how it looks]

```css
#logo{
  position: relative}
  .logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

div.scrollmenu {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<link href="mainmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
<div class="logo">
<img src="images/logo/webmenulogo.png" alt="christian gutierrez" width="70%">
</div>
</head>
<body>

<nav>   
<div class="scrollmenu">

<a href="#Design"><img src="images/distress/designdistress.png" alt="design"      width="70%"></a>
<a href="#Printmaking"><img src="images/distress/printmakingdistress.png"   alt="printmaking" width="70%"></a>
<a href="#Composites"></a>
<a href="#about"><img src="images/distress/aboutdistress.png" alt="about" width="70%"> </a>
<a href="#Contact"><img src="images/distress/contactdistress.png" alt="contact" width="70%"></a>
</div>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To your css, add:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 70vw;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

Comment: I added this to my css and it did center the menu vertically on the homepage however the menu is not centered horizontally.

Comment: Oops my bad, I updated the transform values in the css. You can adjust width and height to suit your taste.